# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.DateTime>'

Tags: c#, linq

```
List<DateTime> listdate = new List<DateTime>();

 var InList = (from b in mstdocstats
                            join a in mstdocs on a.docid = b.docid
                            where a.vtype = 'table'
                            && a.DCREA.Month == "06" && a.DCREA.Year == "2016"
                            select a.docid).ToList();



 var listreaddate = (from b in mstdocstats
                    join a in mstdocs on a.docid = b.docid
                    where InList.Contains(a.docid) && a.vtaid = '2'
              && a.vtype = 'read'
                             select new
                              {
                                   Read_DATE = ((from mstdoc in mstdocs
                                                   where
                                                   mstdoc.docid == a.docid &&
                                                     mstdoc.vtype == "read"
                                                   select new
                                                   {
                                                        mstdoc.DCREA
                                                  }).First().DCREA)
                                }).ToList();
```

but i get an error reporting that C# can't convert the list:

> "Error:Cannot implicitly convert type

```
'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.DateTime>'
```

Kindly guide me with proper solution how can I accomplish this, thanks before...

Comment: At first, you can't define two variables with the same name like `List<DateTime> listdate` and `var listdate` in the same method.

Comment: you have define same variable at two times I mean listdate

Comment: okay, i got it about variable :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following lines create a new anonymous object, which contains a property which is a datetime:

```
                         select new
                          {
                               Read_DATE = ((from mstdoc in mstdocs
                                               where
                                               mstdoc.docid == a.docid &&
                                                 mstdoc.vtype == "read"
                                               select new
                                               {
                                                    mstdoc.DCREA
                                              }).First().DCREA)
                            }
```

try this to get a list of datetimes:

```
                         select  ((from mstdoc in mstdocs
                                               where
                                               mstdoc.docid == a.docid &&
                                                 mstdoc.vtype == "read"
                                               select new
                                               {
                                                    mstdoc.DCREA
                                              }).First().DCREA)
```

Comment: In fact nested anonymous object also redundant, that can be removed,